# MySQL Selecting Table Excluding Columns Which Sum is equal 0

Tags: mysql

I need some help with MySQL syntax.  I need to SELECT whole table, ignoring columns which SUM = 0...

Is it possible knowing that I can't use the columns names in SQL syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `SUM(*)`. it has to be on a particular column, so you'd have to `select sum(a), sum(b), sum(c), etc...`, and once you're doing selecting multiple columns with aggregate functions, you'll need to group on all those fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, pull down the whole record and through the view code, simply don't display the column if it factors out to 0.

Comment: I need to hide / ignore only columns consisting only 0's, can't just ignore "0" fields...

Comment: same answer though, if the sum of ALL records is 0, then do not display that field. If you are trying to dynamically hide or show a column based on this, it will be more specific to the UI framework your using over the database query.